# Running windows Desktop GUI-based Application inside containers

Tags: windows, docker

I want to containerize one of my Windows desktop application(GUI). But i want to use the GUI outside the containers, ( i.e) in the machine where the containers are hosted.

Is there any possible way to share the display inside the container to the host(Only the application display)?

Or is there any way to view the application in the host browser. Are there any display exporters available?

Comment: you don't want to access its display from something like remote desktop, isn't it? I mean a remote connection to your docker.

Comment: Currently i only want to view the application (running inside the container), in my host machine where containers are running. Please suggest any possible way to achieve this